# Teb Local Planner path strange

Tags: ros-noetic, teb-local-planner

https://youtu.be/FdqFL7G832I

I am using teb local planner and it moves like the video above. How do I solve this?

here is my code.

teb_local_planner_params.yaml

```
TebLocalPlannerROS:
  odom_topic: odom
  map_frame: map
    
  # Trajectory
  teb_autosize: True
  dt_ref: 0.3
  dt_hysteresis: 0.1
  global_plan_overwrite_orientation: True
  allow_init_with_backwards_motion: False
  max_global_plan_lookahead_dist: 0.5
  feasibility_check_no_poses: 5
  
  # Robot
  max_vel_x: 0.2
  max_vel_x_backwards: 0.15
  max_vel_y: 0.0
  max_vel_theta: 0.8
  acc_lim_x: 0.15
  acc_lim_y: 0.0
  acc_lim_theta: 0.8

  min_turning_radius: 0.0
  wheelbase: 0.0

  footprint_model:
    types: "polygon"
    vertices: [[-0.17, -0.15], [-0.17, 0.15], [0.17, 0.15], [0.17, -0.15]]

  # GoalTolerance
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.08
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.03
  free_goal_vel: False
  complete_global_plan: True
    
  # Obstacles
  min_obstacle_dist: 0.19
  inflation_dist: 0.5
  include_costmap_obstacles: False
  costmap_obstacles_behind_robot_dist: 1.5
  obstacle_poses_affected: 15
  costmap_converter_plugin: ""
  costmap_converter_spin_thread: True
  costmap_converter_rate: 5

  # Optimization
    
  no_inner_iterations: 5
  no_outer_iterations: 4
  optimization_activate: True
  optimization_verbose: False
  penalty_epsilon: 0.1
  weight_max_vel_x: 1
  weight_max_vel_y: 0
  weight_max_vel_theta: 1
  weight_acc_lim_x: 1
  weight_acc_lim_y: 0
  weight_acc_lim_theta: 1
  weight_kinematics_nh: 1000
  weight_kinematics_forward_drive: 1000
  weight_kinematics_turning_radius: 1
  weight_optimaltime: 1
  weight_shortest_path: 50
  weight_obstacle: 50
  weight_dynamic_obstacle: 10 # not in use yet
  selection_alternative_time_cost: False # not in use yet
  weight_viapoint: 1
  weight_adapt_factor: 2

  # Homotopy Class Planner

  enable_homotopy_class_planning: True
  enable_multithreading: True
  simple_exploration: False
  max_number_classes: 4
  roadmap_graph_no_samples: 15
  roadmap_graph_area_width: 5
  h_signature_prescaler: 0.5 
  h_signature_threshold: 0.1
  obstacle_keypoint_offset: 0.1
  obstacle_heading_threshold: 0.45
  visualize_hc_graph: False
```

costmap_common_params.yaml

```
# obstacle_range: 2.0
# raytrace_range: 2.5
# ax_obstacle_height: 0.60  # assume something like an arm is mounted on top of the robot

# robot_radius: 0.187
footprint: [[-0.2, -0.17], [-0.2, 0.17], [0.2, 0.17], [0.2, -0.17]]
# 345 413 / 0.17 0.205

map_type: voxel
# observation_sources: scan
# scan: {sensor_frame: laser_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
# always_send_full_costmap: true

# inflation_radius: 1.5
# cost_scaling_factor: 5.0

obstacle_layer:
  enabled:              true
  max_obstacle_height:  0.6
  origin_z:             0.0
  z_resolution:         0.2
  z_voxels:             10
  unknown_threshold:    15
  mark_threshold:       0
  combination_method:   1
  track_unknown_space:  true    #true needed for disabling global path planning through unknown space
  obstacle_range: 3.0 # 3.0
  raytrace_range: 3.5 # 3.5
  origin_z: 0.0
  publish_voxel_map: false
  observation_sources:  scan #bump
  scan: {sensor_frame: laser_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
 
#cost_scaling_factor and inflation_radius were now moved to the inflation_layer ns
inflation_layer:
  enabled:              true
  cost_scaling_factor:  15.0  # exponential rate at which the obstacle cost drops off (default: 10)
  inflation_radius:     0.28  # max. distance from an obstacle at which costs are incurred for planning paths.
 
static_layer:
  enabled:              true
```